# Browser based game behind the scenes

Tags: browser

I have a question about how browser based games like ogame, travian works behind the scenes.
In each of these games every player has his own planet or city where have resources like iron, wood, stone or anything else. Each of the planet/city has also appropriate building that produces that resource. And now the point of my topic, how is the game working on server ? I could not image if on server are performed calculations for 10000 players every second that updates they city's states every second, even if only 100 players are online. I think rather there is a function calculating city state after given time as argument like:

```
City calculateCityState(City databaseCity, long msTime);
```

As first argument you pass a city state from database with a timestamp and as second argument you pass time after you would like to have your city with resources and other stuff that changes with time. If you know e.g your current wood amount from database, luberjack production you can easily calculate all resources after msTime. 
What do you think about this ? Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

well, it's a design choice, what makes sense definitely is that it doesn't do it every second if you are offline. On the other hand resources you have may affect other users. Eg. a user wants to see the player with the most resources so that he can attack him. This would mean that these numbers are probably calculated at certain intervals Eg. every 10 minutes.

Comment: In case when one city interacts with another city e.g city1 want to see city2 resources,I rather think then owner of city1 has to calculateCityState() of city2.